# UnsupportedClassVersionError ao tentar gerar um jar

Tags: java

Compilei meu código e tudo mais e quando vou abrir o arquivo `.jar` criado diz *A JNI error has occured*

cmd:

```
C:\Projetos\Java\Projetos\Projeto02>java -jar Gerar.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: principal has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Código:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

class principal {

public static void main(String[] args){

        /*cria o layout e a janela */
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gerador");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());


        /*JLabel do lado dos objetos*/
        GridBagConstraints gbc8 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc8.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc8.gridx = 0;
        gbc8.gridy = 0;
        JLabel itml = new JLabel("Nome do Arquivo:");
        panel.add(itml, gbc8);

        /*Cria e posiciona o JTextField*/
        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc1.gridx = 1;
        gbc1.gridy = 0;
        JTextField texto = new JTextField();
        texto.setColumns(10);
        panel.add(texto, gbc1);

        /*Cria e posiciona o JComboBox*/
        String[] items = {".txt", ".java", ".html", ".php", ".xml", ".odt", ".ods", ".jar", ".sql", ".pdf"};
        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(items);
        combo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc2.gridx = 1;
        gbc2.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(combo, gbc2);

        /*JLabel do lado dos objetos*/
        GridBagConstraints gbc9 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc9.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc9.gridx = 0;
        gbc9.gridy = 1;
        JLabel itm2 = new JLabel("Extens\u00e3o:");
        panel.add(itm2, gbc9);

        /*Cria e posiciona o JButton*/
        GridBagConstraints gbc3 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc3.gridx = 1;
        gbc3.gridy = 2;
        JButton butao = new JButton("Gerar");
        panel.add(butao, gbc3);


        butao.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            String arquivo = texto.getText() + combo.getSelectedItem();
            File file = new File(arquivo);

            texto.setText("");
            combo.setSelectedIndex(0);
            try{file.createNewFile();}catch(IOException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}




        }
        });

        /*Configurações da janela*/
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(250, 250);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Como você está montando esse jar?

Comment: eu to compilando pelo cmd: `jar cfe Gerar.jar principal principal.class principal$1.class "Gerador de arquivos.java"`

Comment: De onde você tirou esse comando? E como está o manifest?

Comment: Sempre usei esse comando para gerar os meus .jar e todos funcionavam e o manifest esta `Main-Class: principal`

Comment: Adicione a pilha de erros completa, porque com certeza não é apenas uma linha o erro.

Comment: adicionei os 2 erros quando eu do 2 cliques no arquivo .jar ele aparece 2 janelas cada um com 1 erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> essa edição ocorreu após a atualização da pergunta com a pilha de erros, não removi a segunda parte da resposta para não perder o contexto gerado antes das  edições.

A mensagem diz que você compilou seu código utilizando o java 9 (versão 53 é java 9), mas a maquina virtual instalada na sua máquina é java 8 (versão 52), conforme disse nos comentários, a versão da JRE precisa ser da mesma versão ou superior ao JDK, o contrario não pode.

Você precisa instalar uma JRE do java 9 ou recompila-lo usando o JDK na versão 8.

---

Comigo funcionou com o comando abaixo, criado conforme a [**documentação**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html):

```
jar cfve Gerar.jar principal principal.class principal$1.class
```

Saída dele:

```
manifesto adicionado
adicionando: principal.class(entrada = 2091) (saÝda= 1271)(compactado 39%)
adicionando: principal$1.class(entrada = 1590) (saÝda= 840)(compactado 47%)
```

Arquivos gerados pelo comando `javac principal.java` e pelo comando acima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o programa abriu normalmente sem nenhum tipo de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mudo nada ainda continua com o mesmo erro

Comment: @ClockWork como eu disse, não tem como te ajudar só com as informações que você passou, seu problema não é reproduzivel. Tentei reproduzir com o que deu e funcionou. Tente executar o jar via cmd com `java -jar Gerar.jar` e ve se mostra erros. Se sim, edite a pergunta e forneça mais informações com esse erro.

Comment: vou postar os erros que dão após desinstalar td e instalar dnv ta aparecendo no cmd os erros

Comment: @ClockWork agora sim, o erro é claro, você compilou seu código numa versao da jdk superior a versao da maquina virtual. As maquina virtual precisa ser da mesma versão ou superior ao JDK, o contrario não pode.

Comment: agora ele não roda de usando `java "Classe principal"` não entendi, oque devo fazer?

Comment: @ClockWork releia meu ultimo comentário, ele é a resposta e solução do problema..

Comment: Entendi funcionou so tive que recompilar o código dnv vlw pela ajuda

Comment: @ClockWork Editei a resposta, mas recomendo que revise as versoes instaladas do JDK e da JRE, e certifique-se de que esteja conforme a sugestão da edição

Comment: acabei de ver isso, ta td certo jdk1.8.0_151 e jre1.8.0_151

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67554/discussion-between-clockwork-and-articuno).